# Spring JMS: Do I need two jmsListenerConnectionFactory beans?

Tags: spring-jms

`24.6.1 Enable listener endpoint annotations`

I am confused about this section in the Spring JMS documentation.  I want to annotate my JMS endpoints and I have queue and topic listeners in my application.

But, the DefaultJmsListenerConnectionFactory has a `Boolean pubSubDomain` attribute.  The docs show a single one with a standard bean name of "jmsListenerContainerFactory" and the JavaConfig code example shows it to be "pubSubDomain = null" (e.g. not set).

Does "null" for this attribute mean this default infrastructure bean supports BOTH topics and queues?

Or, do I need to set up 2 of them (one for queues and one for topics)?   If so, what is the name of the standard bean for "topics" vs. "queues"?

Comment: Yes you need two, but I don't know what you mean by "standard bean".

Comment: Sorry. By 'standard bean', I mean, one that the Spring infrastructure will automatically use for a JmsListener anotation when creating a MessageListenerContainer.  For instance, if "jmsListenerContainerFactory" is the default bean Spring uses for any JmsListener( destination="someQueue") annotation, then what would be the default bean name for JmsListener(destination="someTopic") annotation?

Comment: Or, does the Spring JmsListener annotation post-processor figure out that it is processing a JmsListener() annotation for a Topic and make sure the MessageListenerContainer it configures ONLY has 1 listener?  All the while, for queues it honors the concurrency setting as configured (e.g., setConcurrency("3-10"))

Answer (score 1):

It's still not really clear what you are asking. Common properties are provided on the annotation.

The listener container factory provides a set of other common properties for [all] `@JmsListener`s that use it.

By default, you'll get a default set of properties (`cacheLevel`, `pubSubDomain`, `messageConverter` for example).

You can override the defaults applied to all listeners that don't have an explicit container factory set by defining a bean named `jmsListenerContainerFactory`.

If you want some other subset of listeners to have different properties to the default, you need to explicitly define an additional container factory bean, and configure the appropriate listeners to be wired up using that factory.

Comment: OK.  That answers my question.  It sounds like the default 'jmsListenerContainerFactory' would not apply very well to both topics and queues. I mean, if you set concurrency to anything more than 1, it would  result in duplicate messages by the topic listeners.  Yet, if you set concurrency to only 1, it would not be very scalable for queue listeners.  That said, I will just go ahead and make Spring's default 'jmsListenerContainerFactory' only used by my queue listeners and create an additional listener container factory bean for my topics.  Thanks!